# Numpy Saving Text Incorrectly

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, text-files

I'm currently writing a python 3 function that takes in a numpy array and prints the entire array to a text file but it first appends a 0 to the last row.  For example if I give it np.eye(3),

```
1 0 0 
0 0 1
0 0 1
```

it should write,

```
1 0 0 
0 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

to a text file.  Although the following code,

```
def addTo(array,textFile):
  file=open(textFile,'ab')
  (numRows,numColumns)=array.shape
  main=array[0:numRows-1,:]
  endRow=array[numRows-1,:]
  newEndRow=np.append(endRow, [0])
  np.savetxt(file,main, fmt='%10.5f', newline=os.linesep)
  np.savetxt(file,newEndRow[np.newaxis], fmt='%10.5f', newline=os.linesep)
  file.close()

addTo(np.eye(3),'test1.txt')
```

keeps returning

```
   1.00000    0.00000    0.00000
   0.00000    1.00000    0.00000
   0.00000    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000
```

It's strange because every line is indented in the text file.  Is there anyway to keep numpy from doing this?

Comment: `np.eye(3)` returns the identity matrix - which is 1's along the diagonal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). In which case the output it's producing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

what is it that bothers you?  Your format specifies a field 10 char long, with 5 decimals.  That's what you get:

```
In [357]:  fmt='%10.5f'
In [358]: fmt%1
Out[358]: '   1.00000'
In [359]: fmt%0
Out[359]: '   0.00000'
```

To get `'1 0 0'` you need to give it a different `fmt`, something like `%d`.  Are you familiar with the Python formatting `%` specifications?